# How to add the bonus?

Tags: java, file

I have done a code, which reads a file consists a number of employees, salary, and their rankings, based on their rankings how can we add the bonus percent to their salary...

```
 String phrases;  
 int salary=0;
 try {
    FileReader in = new FileReader("bonus.txt"); 
    BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(in);   
    while ((phrases = readFile.readLine()) != null) {   
       System.out.println(phrases);
       double bonus;

       if(phrases.contains("1")){
          bonus=salary/0.03;
          System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);
       }else if(phrases.contains("2")){
          bonus=salary/0.08;
          System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);
       }else if(phrases.contains("3")){
          bonus=salary/0.20;
          System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);
       }

       // System.out.println();
    }
    readFile.close();
    in.close(); 
 }catch (IOException e) {        
    System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
 }
```

It outputs:

```
 Jame   900000  1
 Bonus: 0.0
 Jane   60000   2
 Bonus: 0.0
 Don    866000  3
 Bonus: 0.0
```

I have no idea why

Comment: have you checked that you are getting "phrase" a value..??

Comment: isn't phrase reading the file?I am unclear

Comment: yes debug and check if you are getting a phrase read from the file each time, giving 1,2 or 3

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: I am pretty its not, becuase if it did then the ouput should be:      
      Jame   900000  1
      Bonus: 30000000.0
      Jane   60000   2
      Bonus: 750000.0
      Don    866000  3
      Bonus: 4330000.0

Comment: how can I make sure phrase reads the rank value?

Comment: `salary` and `bonus` are initially set to `0`, but they are never updated. Thus, the bonus will always be 0.

Comment: how can I fix it, because if I didn't declare it, it gives error

Comment: I have fixed it for bonus, but for salary it is giving me error

Comment: Can you please update the code you are using?

Comment: your Salary is always 0 so you will obviously get 0 as the answer.... you have to read the salary value from the txt or input them by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an employeeBonus.txt file like below.

```
Jame    900000  2
Jane    60000   1
Don     866000  3
```

I think you will have three tokens as a string so, you can use a stringtokenizer class in order to get a salary and a grade.

At the first line of file is

```
Jame    900000  2
```

and the result of encoded string was

```
Jame%20%20%20%20900000%092
```

I've finally found the content of text file was mixed with a space and tab character by URL encoding.

So, the usage of this type is as follows,

```
StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer(phrase, " \t");
```

It takes a salary and an identifier of bonus value from third and second token.

```
name = stTok.nextToken(); //first token
salary = Integer.valueOf(stTok.nextToken()).intValue(); //second token
grade = stTok.nextToken();
```

[source code]

```
package com.tobee.tests.inout;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CheckBounsFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name, phrase, grade;
        double bonus = 0;
        int salary = 0;
        BufferedReader readFile = null;
        try {
            readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resource/aa/employeeBonus.txt"));

            while ((phrase = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(phrase);

                StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer(phrase, " \t");

                name = stTok.nextToken();

                salary = Integer.valueOf(stTok.nextToken()).intValue();

                grade = stTok.nextToken();

                if(grade!= null && !grade.equals(""))
                {
                    if (grade.equals("1")) {
                        bonus = salary / 0.03;
                    } else if (grade.equals("2")) {
                        bonus = salary / 0.08;

                    } else if (grade.equals("3")) {
                        bonus = salary / 0.20;
                    }

                    System.out.printf("name[%s]salary[%d]Bonus[%f] \n",name, salary, bonus);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                readFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[result]

```
name[Jame]salary[900000]Bonus[30000000.000000] 
name[Jane]salary[60000]Bonus[750000.000000] 
name[Don]salary[866000]Bonus[4330000.000000]
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
 at CheckBounsFromFile.main(CheckBounsFromFile.java:21)

Comment: Well, can you show me the contents of the txt file you have?

Comment: bonus.txt..file i meant

Comment: `Jame   900000  1`
`Jane   60000   2`                                                                                                                                                                      
`Don    866000  3`    this is what I have done on the bonus txt file... each on a separate line

Comment: At the line...'new StringTokenizer(phrase, " ");' Did you have the second argument with a space between the double quotation?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what u are trying to say?

Comment: You might have a NoSuchElementException when the second argument of StringTokenizer class is a "" not a " " (with space)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171202/discussion-between-xox-and-tommybee).

Answer (score 0):

You check the condition with equals method but your phrases variable contains different value rather than 1,2,3 that's why you get the bonus 0.

```
if(phrases.contains("1")){
       bonus=salary/0.03;

}else if(phrases.contains("2")){
       bonus=salary/0.08;

}else if(phrases.contains("3")){
        bonus=salary/0.20;
}
```

or you can get the last parameter with:

```
phrases.substring(phrases.length()-1, phrases.length())
```

you can get the third parameter using **contains** or **split** method.
Please check this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

**And one more thing your salary is always zero (0)**. please correct it

I have posted full code here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class SubClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrases;  
        int salary=0;
        try {
            FileReader in = new FileReader("bonus.txt"); 
            BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(in);   
            while ((phrases = readFile.readLine()) != null) {   
                    System.out.println(phrases);
                    phrases = phrases.trim().replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ");
                    String splitStr [] = phrases.split(" "); 
                    double bonus;
                    salary = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]);
                    if(splitStr[2].contains("1")){
                        bonus=salary/0.03;
                        System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);

                 }else if(splitStr[2].contains("2")){
                        bonus=salary/0.08;
                        System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);

                 }else if(splitStr[2].contains("3")){
                         bonus=salary/0.20;
                         System.out.println("Bonus: " + bonus);

                 }

                 // System.out.println();
                }
            readFile.close();
            in.close(); 
        }catch (IOException e) {        
            System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
                System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Jame 900000 1                                                                            
(next line)     Bonus: 30000000.0                                                                             (next line)     Jane 60000 2                                                                              
(next line)     Bonus: 750000.0                                                                             (next line)     Don 866000 3                                                                             
(next line)     Bonus: 4330000.0

Comment: I am trying myself...wait a moment please

Comment: Please check it now... thanks and accept the answer.

Comment: its showing me error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Q11.main(Q11.java:17)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171199/discussion-between-amit-and-xox).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers appear to not cater for the fact that your `salary` variable is always `0`, thus, your `bonus` calculation, which **depends** on your salary value will always be 0.

Assuming that this: `Jame   900000  1` is a sample line from your text file, there are various issues with your code.

1. The first issue is this: `(phrases.equals("1")`. If phrase will be equal to the text in the current line you are processing: `Jame   900000  1`, this statement (and the same for the other two) will never return true, thus the bonus will never be calculated.
2. The second issue is that you are never extracting the `salary` value.

You will need to replace this:

```
while ((phrases = readFile.readLine()) != null) {   
    System.out.println(phrases);
    if(phrases.equals("1")){
```

With something like this:

```
while ((phrases = readFile.readLine()) != null) {   
    System.out.println(phrases);
    String[] employeeData = phrases.split("\\t");   //This assumes that your data is split by tabs.
    salary = Double.parse(employeeData[1]);
    if("1".equals(employeeData[2])) {
        bonus = salary * 0.03;
    }
    ...
```